# Update custom entity with Dynamics Crm 2016 workflow

Tags: workflow, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using Dynamics Crm 2016 in my job. There are custom entities with custom fields. I want to create a workflow to update a custom field on a custom entity. This field is a date time field. What I want is to do is have the workflow run daily to check this field on each record (for this custom entity) and if the date is today's date or later, update the owner of this entity. Can this be done entirely in Crm or will I have to write my own plugin code?

Answer (score 0):

Straightway you don't have nothing like your ask but, you can create on your workflow is Add a wait condition to start every day or every 1 day.
After update your date to trigger your workflow.

This is a basic on the image but you can work around this to your goal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSmT4.jpg

Cheers,
Jorge Cunha

Comment: Gracias Jorge, that makes sense. What I'm not seeing though is any way to update my custom fields in a workflow step. They simply don't appear in any drop downs. Any idea if that is possible. meaning, I have a custom entity called announcement and i want to update a custom field on that when a certain condition is true.

Comment: I don't really understand your question now but you can put on the wait condition when your condition is true and update your field so you don't need to run everyday, because your workflow is going to update when the condition is true. I think this is what you asking

Comment: Sorry Jorge, I wasn't very clear. I'v figured out the problem I was trying to explain there, and your post helped me with the overall solution. Thank you very much.